# How to prove that $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-x^2}\cos xdx>0$

Tags: calculus, integration

> How to prove that $\displaystyle I=\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-x^2}\cos(x)\mathrm{d}x>0$

Clearly, $\displaystyle I=\int_0^\pi \left(e^{-x^2}-e^{-(x+\pi)^2}\right)\cos(x)\mathrm{d}x$, but this does not help.

Or else, $$I=\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-x^2}\mathrm{d}\sin(x)
=2\int_0^{2\pi} xe^{-x^2}\sin(x)\mathrm{d}x
=2\int_0^\pi \left(xe^{-x^2}-(x+\pi)e^{-(x+\pi)^2}\right)\sin(x)\mathrm{d}x.$$ This time, $\sin(x)$ has a good sign, but $xe^{-x^2}$ has no monotonicity property.

Any ideas?

Comment: Another MSE 'clearly' that _clearly_ needs elucidation.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks for catching that. Way off

Comment: The key here is split the interval into two parts $[0,a],[a,2\pi]$ such that $|e^{-x^2}\cos x|$ is small in $[a, 2\pi]$.

Comment: I think the first quadrant of the unit circle dominates.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: $f(x)=e^{-x^2}-e^{-(x+\pi)^2}$ is increasing for very small $x$.

Comment: Not a proof, but: the red area is larger than the blue area. https://imgur.com/a/Nr9PAB3

Answer (score 8):

Use the inequality [$\cos x\ge 1-\frac{x^2}2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2507219/215011) to write:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-x^2}\cos x\,{\rm d}x\ge\int_0^{2\pi}\left( e^{-x^2}-\frac{x^2}2 e^{-x^2}\right)\,{\rm d}x=A - B.$$ To show $A>B$, compute a lower bound for $A$ using the inequality [$e^{-t}\ge 1-t$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1714172/215011):
$$A:=\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-x^2}\,{\rm d}x\ge\int_0^1 e^{-x^2}\,{\rm d}x\ge\int_0^1\left(1- x^2\right)\,{\rm d}x=\frac23.$$ Find an upper bound for $B$ using the fact [$\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-x^2}\,{\rm d}x=\frac{\sqrt\pi}4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1596976/215011):
$$B:=\frac12\int_0^{2\pi}x^2e^{-x^2}\,{\rm d}x\le\frac12\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-x^2}\,{\rm d}x=\frac{\sqrt\pi}8.$$

---

This approach also proves the non-trivial case ($t>\frac\pi2$) for the general result
$$
\int_0^t e^{-x^2}\cos x\,{\rm d}x>0\qquad\text {for all $t>0$}.
$$

Answer (score 5):

The integral $I_1=\int_0^{\pi/2}f(x)\,dx$ is positive (as the integrand is positive in this interval) and $$I_1>\int_0^{\pi/4}f(x)\,dx>\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot \frac{e^{-\pi^2/16}}{\sqrt{2}}\tag{1}$$ as the integrand is decreasing in this interval and hence greater than $f(\pi/4)$.

Further $I_2=\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}f(x)\,dx$ is negative with $$|I_2|\leq \int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}|f(x)|\,dx<\pi \cdot e^{-\pi^2/4}\tag{2}$$ and our job is done if we can show that RHS of $(1)$ is greater than that of $(2)$.

This requires us to prove that $e^{3\pi^2/16}>4\sqrt {2}$ or $$\frac{3\pi^2}{8}>5\log 2$$ This is possible by noting that $\log 2<0.7$ and $\pi>3.14$.

Comment: How do you get Inequalities (1) and (2)?

Comment: @Hans: updated my answer with some details. The inequalities are not tricky but rather based on well known properties of integrals.

Comment: Yeah, I should have noticed earlier...

Answer (score 1):

Bounds for the integral on subintervals:
$[0,\pi/4]: I_{11}>\frac1{\sqrt2}e^{-\pi^2/16}\\
[\pi/4,\pi/2]: I_{12}>(1-\frac1{\sqrt2})e^{-\pi^2/4}\\
[\pi/2,\pi]: I_{2}>-e^{-\pi^2/4}\\
[\pi,3\pi/2]: I_{3}>-e^{-\pi^2}\\
[3\pi/2,2\pi]: I_{4}>e^{-4\pi^2}\\
$

Adding these we have
$$I=\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-x^2}\cos x\, dx>\frac1{\sqrt2}(e^{-\pi^2/16}-e^{-\pi^2/4})-e^{-\pi^2}>
\frac1{\sqrt2}(e^{-0.64}-e^{-9/4})-e^{-9}>0.
$$

Answer (score -1):

The integral is the area under the curve.

The product of $e^{-x^2}$ and $\cos(x)$ is mostly positive in the interval given for x .
Think of it pointwise, at every x in the interval. You may split the integral into the negative and positive area parts of $\cos(x)$ since the $e^{-x^2}$ Gaussian function is positive and compare or bound those pieces for a formal proof.

[image]

Comment: This is persuasion, not a proof.

Comment: answers are open to expert proof writers

Comment: I would not consider $e^{x^2} \cos x$ as "mostly positive" from $0$ to $2\pi$. The product is negative on $(\pi/2, 3\pi/2)$ and positive on the other two open subintervals.

Comment: Nice graph which shows that the subintegral on the subinterval $[0,\frac\pi 4]$ dominates. And it is positive.